# Подключение стилей перед </body>

Tags: php, wordpress

Как в вордпресс подключить стили перед закрывающим тегом body?
[wp-kama - wp_enqueue_style()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_style)

> С версии 3.3. wp_enqueue_style() можно вызывать в середине документа. В этом случае файл будет выведен в подвале, перед тегом  (где вызывается wp_footer()).

как-то слишком мало информации на этом сайте про данное подключение. 
В середине документа как именно нужно подключать?
через хук `wp_enqueue_scripts` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, именно через хук wp_enqueue_style(). Хук ведь ничего не делает сам по себе, он просто записывает информацию о стилях в некий внутренний массив WordPress. Позже, в момент срабатывания события wp_footer, WordPress вытаскивает все стили из массива и вставляет их в подвал сайта.

Comment: это что, какой-то новый хук enqueue_style()?

Comment: Нет, этот хук всегда был. Я имел ввиду wp_enqueue_style()

Comment: так функцию wp_enqueue_style() нужно вызывать в каком-то хуке. А такого хука как `wp_enqueue_style()` нет. Как-то не совсем понятно

Comment: В том-то и дело, что вне всяких хуков. Допустим, на странице, в ходе вывода поста на экран можно написать `wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );` и все будет будет ок. Сама wp_enqueue_style молча занесет инфу в массив, а стиль будет выведен позже, в подвале.

Comment: блин, всего лишь добавить "вне хука" в вышеприведённой цитате, и куча вопросов бы отпало

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: кстати стили не подключаются перед body. Вставил данный код `wp_enqueue_style('theme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0.0', 'screen, print');` в файле `functions.php` . WordPress 4.7.6 с темой

Comment: т.е. подключаются также в теге head. Есть ли ещё вариант, как можно подключить стили по вордпрессовски перед </body> ?

Comment: Через хук wp_enqueue_script. Но лучше задать новый вопрос

Comment: И я не понял - вопрос изменён? Я с телефона не могу увидеть правки. Был разговор вроде про Footer

Comment: вопрос тотже, не важно, перед </body> или перед футером, нужно перенести из head стили

Comment: > кстати стили не подключаются перед body.

Потому и не подключаются, что код вставили в function.php. Этот файл исполняется в самом начале загрузки сайта, до header, а kama пишет, что стили уйдут в подвал, если вызвать enqueue_style в середине страницы. Вставьте вызов wp_enqueue_style куда-нибудь в single.php и увидите результат. А лучше - в хук wp_footer в functions.php